# How to automate multiple replacement?

Tags: r, dataframe, str-replace

Let's assume I have the following data:

```
df = data.frame(x = c("ciao he is a good researcher","he is working well on political franchise",
                        "gionny and I have to sort this issue","r leave us in peace"),stringsAsFactors = F)
rep = data.frame(x=c("political_risk","good_researcher"),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to replace "rep" into "df".

I used to run this code but now I get an error (`Error in UseMethod("type") :  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "data.frame"`):

```
result = df %>% str_replace_all(rep)
```

It works if I do:

```
str_replace_all(df$x, c("political risk" = "political_risk", "good researcher" = "good_researcher"))
```

Yet, I want to do it in one shot.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   mutate(x = str_replace_all(x,
      setNames(rep$x, c("political risk", "good researcher"))))
```